# RestSharp Serialize JSON in camelCase

Tags: json, restsharp, simplejson, camelcasing

I am trying to post JSON in camelCase, and have followed the instructions here:

https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/Deserialization#overriding-jsonserializationstrategy

```
public class CamelCaseSerializerStrategy : PocoJsonSerializerStrategy
{
    protected override string MapClrMemberNameToJsonFieldName(string clrPropertyName)
    {
    return char.ToLower(clrPropertyName[0]) + clrPropertyName.Substring(1);
    }
}
```

Then I am creating a new client with this code:

```
var client = new RestClient(_baseUrl);
SimpleJson.CurrentJsonSerializerStrategy = new CamelCaseSerializerStrategy();
```

Still, when making a request, the serializer is not activated.  The RestSharp documentation is all over the place and largely incorrect.  Looking at the source ([RestRequest.AddBody](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/master/RestSharp/RestRequest.cs#L230)), it doesn't look like the SerializerStrategy is used at all.

I was looking for a way to make this change at the client level, or somewhere that doesn't require modifying each request.

I've seen [this blog](http://blog.patrickmriley.net/2014/02/restsharp-using-jsonnet-serializer.html) - and maybe that's the only way.  Seems like a huge step back for RestSharp if you can only change serialization strategies at the request level.

Comment: you might want to try and create the client after you created a new strategy instance

Answer (score 11):

I faced the exact same problem. Fortunately, I managed to solve it by following the instructions presented [here](https://github.com/adamfisher/RestSharp.Newtonsoft.Json).

Basically, for each request, you have to set the `JsonSerializer` to `NewtonsoftJsonSerializer`. Example:

```
var request = new RestRequest();
request.JsonSerializer = new NewtonsoftJsonSerializer();
```

The source for the `NewtonsoftJsonSerializer` below:

```
public NewtonsoftJsonSerializer()
{
     ContentType = "application/json";
     _serializer = new JsonSerializer
     {
          MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore,
          NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include,
          DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Include
     };
}

public NewtonsoftJsonSerializer(JsonSerializer serializer)
{
     ContentType = "application/json";
     _serializer = serializer;
}


public string Serialize(object obj)
{
     using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
     {
         using (var jsonTextWriter = new JsonTextWriter(stringWriter))
         {
             jsonTextWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
             jsonTextWriter.QuoteChar = '"';

             _serializer.Serialize(jsonTextWriter, obj);

             var result = stringWriter.ToString();
             return result;
          }
     }
}

    public string DateFormat { get; set; }
    public string RootElement { get; set; }
    public string Namespace { get; set; }
    public string ContentType { get; set; }
}
```

Hope it solves your problem!

Comment: Worked only after adding RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json to RestRequest object. Thank you

Answer (score 7):

RestSharp.Serializers.NewtonsoftJson

dotnet add package RestSharp.Serializers.NewtonsoftJson

or

[Manage Nuget Package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NX8hH.png)

then

```
using RestSharp.Serializers.NewtonsoftJson;
...
public myRestSharpMethod() {

   ... 

   var client = new RestClient(url);

   client.UseNewtonsoftJson();

   // code continues..
}
```

hope it helps!

Answer (score 4):

I'm using RestSharp 105.2.3 and the proposed solution from [RestSharp wiki](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/Serialization#overriding-jsonserializationstrategy) works fine for me. I've tried to assign my strategy object to the SimpleJson.CurrentJsonSerializerStrategy property both before and after creating a RestClient instance, both ways worked.

Probably your problem is somewhere else.

Comment: The code in the question worked for me too, and actually helped answer what I was looking for.

Comment: The link no-longer works are you able to include the code from the wiki in your answer? (or is it obsolete now? I'm using RestSharp 106.6.9

Answer (score 2):

**Using Restsharp v107.0 or newer**

RestSharp has decided to bring back Newtonsoft.JSON support in version v107.0, so you can set Restsharp to use Newtonsoft.JSON with camelCase using:

Send code:

```
var restSharpClient = new RestClient("https://my.api.com")
                .UseSerializer(new JsonNetSerializer());

var request = new Company();
request.CompanyName = "ACME";

var restSharpRequest = new RestSharp.RestRequest("client", RestSharp.Method.POST);

restSharpRequest.AddJsonBody(request);

var restSharpResponse = restSharpClient.Execute(restSharpRequest);
```

Serializer:

```
private class JsonNetSerializer : RestSharp.Serialization.IRestSerializer
{
    public string Serialize(object obj) =>
        Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);

    public string Serialize(Parameter parameter) =>
        Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parameter.Value);

    public T Deserialize<T>(RestSharp.IRestResponse response) =>
        Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(response.Content);

    public string[] SupportedContentTypes { get; } = {
        "application/json", "text/json", "text/x-json", "text/javascript", "*+json"
    };

    public string ContentType { get; set; } = "application/json";

    public RestSharp.DataFormat DataFormat { get; } = RestSharp.DataFormat.Json;
}
```

Request class:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Company {
    [JsonProperty("companyName")]
    public String CompanyName { get; set; }
}
```

Reference: https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/Serialization

**Using Restsharp v106.0 or older**:

You can use this library: https://github.com/adamfisher/RestSharp.Serializers.Newtonsoft.Json
and set the serializer before each request

Comment: adding small change if it helps anyone -Use Serializer now uses delegate  .UseSerializer(() => new JsonNetSerializer());

Answer (score 1):

Using the link from Alex Che solved most of the issue. You may still have some troubles if you want everything to be lower case. Here's an example:

```
using System.Linq;
using RestSharp;

public class Demo
{
    public IRestResponse<ExampleOutputDto> ExecuteDemo()
    {
        // Convert casing
        SimpleJson.CurrentJsonSerializerStrategy = new SnakeJsonSerializerStrategy();

        const string uri = "http://foo.bar/";
        const string path = "demo";
        var inputDto = new ExampleInputDto
        {
            FooBar = "foobar",
            Foo = "foo"
        };

        var client = new RestClient(uri);
        var request = new RestRequest(uri, Method.POST)
            .AddJsonBody(inputDto);
        return client.Execute<ExampleOutputDto>(request);
    }
}

public class ExampleInputDto
{
    public string FooBar { get; set; }
    public string Foo { get; set; }
}

public class ExampleOutputDto
{
    public string Response { get; set; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Credit to https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/Deserialization#overriding-jsonserializationstrategy
/// </summary>
public class SnakeJsonSerializerStrategy : PocoJsonSerializerStrategy
{
    protected override string MapClrMemberNameToJsonFieldName(string clrPropertyName)
    {
        //PascalCase to snake_case
        return string.Concat(clrPropertyName.Select((x, i) => i > 0 && char.IsUpper(x) ? "_" + char.ToLower(x).ToString() : char.ToLower(x).ToString()));
    }
}
```

In this example, `FooBar` will be converted to `foo_bar` and `Foo` will be converted to `Foo`. Additionally, the response will be deserialized properly, i.e. `response` will be converted to `Response`.

Answer (score 1):

Use PocoJsonSerializerStrategy as base for your new Class

```
internal class CamelCaseJsonSerializerStrategy : PocoJsonSerializerStrategy
    {
        protected override string MapClrMemberNameToJsonFieldName(string clrPropertyName)
        {
            if (clrPropertyName.Count() >= 2)
            {
                return char.ToLower(clrPropertyName[0]).ToString() + clrPropertyName.Substring(1);
            }
            else
            {
                //Single char name e.g Property.X
                return clrPropertyName.ToLower();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The order doesn't seem to matter. I'm trying to do similar and with no joy.

It seems strange though that you can't override the serializer and deserializer on a more global level though (via config perhaps) without having to knock up some kind of wrapper for the RestRequest object. Having to set it on a per request basis (especially when you're doing alot of requests) just seems to be asking for trouble.

Answer (score 0):

From RestSharp documentation: https://restsharp.dev/serialization.html#json

You can define the camelCase in `JsonSerializerOptions` like below:

```
restClient = new RestClient();
restClient.UseSystemTextJson(new JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase });
```